# Inheritance-related c++ compilation error

Tags: c++

I'm writing some c++ code which looks like:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}
  void foo(int a) {}
  virtual void foo(int a, int b) = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  virtual void foo(int a, int b) {}
};

int main()
{
  Derived o;
  o.foo(1);

  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

At first I thought of a compilator bug, but after trying with different ones and always getting the same result, I realize it must be part of the standard.
Can somebody please point out the reason for that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of name hiding.

Declaring a function in a derived class with the same name as those in the base class *hides* the ones in the base class.

If you also want to be able to call `void foo(int)` on `Derived`, put in a using-declaration:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
  using Base::foo; //here
  virtual void foo(int a, int b) {}
};
```